# Toggle switch display on selected

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

I would like to display creating product in admin section sub categories in tree only when selected else closed in woocommerce product categoreis. How can I achieve this ? Presently it appears like this. Tried css but didn't work.

```html
<li id="tire_sizes-52"><label class="radiall"><input value="52" type="checkbox" name="tax_input[tire_sizes][]" id="in-tire_sizes-52"> 145</label><ul class="children">

<li id="tire_sizes-62"><label class="radiall"><input value="62" type="checkbox" name="tax_input[tire_sizes][]" id="in-tire_sizes-62"> 65</label>    <ul class="children">

<li id="tire_sizes-87"><label class="radiall"><input value="87" type="checkbox" name="tax_input[tire_sizes][]" id="in-tire_sizes-87"> 15</label></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
```

I want it closed and open only if selected

Answer (score 0):

```js
// if a checkbox has a child, add a css class="has-children"
// select them
const parents = document.querySelectorAll('.has-children')

const caches = parents.map(() => ([]))

function clear(parent) {
 const id = parent.getAttribute('id');
 const ul = parent.querySelector('.children');
 ul.css.display = 'none'; // hide from the DOM
 // you may also need to remove it from the DOM
 /*
 children = [];
 while (parent.firstChild) {
  const firstChild = parent.firstChild
  parent.removeChild(firstChild)
  caches[id].push(firstChild);
 }*/
}

// inital setup
parents.forEach(function (parent) {
 const id = parent.getAttribute('id');
 clear(parent);
 
 // setup listen for changes to parents
 parent.addEventListener('change', function() {
   let child;
   if (child = parent.querySelector('children')) {
    if (child.css.display === 'block') {
     clear(parent)
    } else {
     //caches[this.getAttribute('id')].forEach(c => 
     //  this.appendChild(c)
     delete caches[this.getAttribute('id')]
     const ul = parent.querySelector('.children');
     ul.css.display = 'block'; // show from bom
    }
 });

})
```

something like this. Checkout jquery it may be easier

If this is right, please give me points, i'm a nooob

I haven't executed this code , so it will need your attentions. but that is the essance of it. As I say. look into jquery. This can be accomplished in 3 lines of code.

Comment: No it didn't work.css is a better option may be input[type=”checkbox”]:checked +label +  {
    display: block!important;
} but something is wrong here

Comment: The display block i important  will break my change of the display propery. I cant remember the order of css chain

Comment: Cant understand what u said